# An example of an Angular app like their Docs page wanted

Tags: angular, angular-material

I guess [Angular Docs page](https://angular.io/docs) is built with Angular, right? :)

Are there the sources of this (or similar) Angular app somewhere?

Comment: try coding it up first

Comment: I guess we will but it would be great to have a ready-to-use template for such app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have it open-sourced on github: https://github.com/angular/angular.io

**EDIT**

The above link is the archived version, which you might still want to check out. The current project is here: https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/aio

Comment: You are linking the archived repo. The correct link is https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/aio

Comment: Pardon me, overlooked it, will fix

Answer (score 1):

It might be using angular, but it could be using [polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/) which is a framework for creating Progressive Web Apps. Polymer is composed of elements, and if you are looking for the menu and sidebar, it is the app-layout which can be found on [webcomponents](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/app-layout)